Expected number of cards greater than at least one neighbor

Six cards numbered from $1$ to $6$ are randomly shuffled and then arranged in a circle. Given that $1$ and $6$ are adjacent to each other, what is the expected number of cards larger than at least one of its neighbors?

I solved it as follows:
Let's fix positions of $1$ and $6$ and label all the other numbers as follows:
$1-A-B-C-D-6$
$$E[N] = E[1]+E[A]+E[B]+E[C]+E[D]+E[6]$$
where $N$ is the number of cards larger than at least one of its neighbors.
The expectations are simply just the probability each number is larger than at least one
of it's neighbor.
$E[1] = 0$, since it's the smallest number.
$E[A] = 1$, since $A$ is next to $1$.
$E[B] = \frac{4}{6}$, $4$ out of $3!$ arrangements will satisfy the condition.
$E[C] = \frac{4}{6}$, same as $B$.
$E[D] = \frac{1}{2}$, since it's right next to $6$.
$E[6] = 1$, since it's the largest number.
Hence, $E[N] = \frac{23}{6}$.
Does my solution seem right?

Yes - using linearity of expectation.
